# Testing Ajax using localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to test a simple Ajax script using Javascript and I'm not receiving a response. The PHP script is placed in the `htdocs` folder of the local server and the HTML page that includes the Ajax calls is placed on my desktop. A `readyState` of 4 is received from the server but the status returned is 0, not 200.

The error generated on Firefox state:

`NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied.`

Here is the section of code responsible for calling the Ajax object:

```
var myRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();

function callAjax() {
    var url = "localhost/clock.php";
    var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);
    myRequest. open("GET", url + "?rand=" + myRandom, true);
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = responseAjax;
    myRequest.send(null);
}

function responseAjax() {
    if(myRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if(myRequest.status == 200) {
            var now = new Date();
            var localTime = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
            var serverTime = myRequest.responseText;
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "Server: " + serverTime + "<br />Local: " + localTime;
        } else {
            alert("An error has occurred: " + myRequest.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer insight to my problem?

OSX 10.8.5
MAMP version 2.1.3

Comment: can you try with `var url = "http://localhost/clock.php";` first?

Comment: why is the document on your desktop and not in the htdocs folder?

Comment: You should create site folder in htdocs folder and copy there clock.php then try with this                                          var url="http://localhost/site_folder/clock.php"

Comment: @user2684308 http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 5):

You say your file is on the desktop. You cannot open a local file ( file:// ) and do ajax. You need to access the file through your Apache server ( http:// ).

Comment: yes, adding the proper protocol would help and did help. I prefixed the path with the HTTP:// and it worked. Thank you all for your help.